How do I create a User Customizable popup menu from an existing CMenu?
I use MFCs CMenu to create right-click popup menus for many user commands (C++ using VS 2022). Is there already a framework for allowing user customization of these popup menus? Meaning the user will enter an edit mode and then can reorder, group, or separate the current popup menu commands.
I just need to know before I reinvent the wheel and create a menu customizer class.
User Model for Customization
I tried using the wrapper class BCGSoft CBCGPToolbarCustomize but this only takes CFrameWnd not CMenu.

I believe customization support is only available for CMFCToolBars but not for CMenus. If nothing else you can inspect the CMFCToolBar implementation for inspiration. If you haven't installed the MFC source code you can do so from the Visual Studio Installer.

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll continue doing some research :)

I think the app and frame-window classes must be of  -Ex type, eg CWinAppEx and CFrameWndEx/CMDIFrameWndEx. The toolbar then contains a small "Customize" button, which has menu customization options and a customization dialog, all generated by the Wizard and working from the start. Not sure how popup menus integrate though. Create several test-projects with different "Project Style" options to find which is best for you (and I would say disable the "Themes" options and stick with the Default Native one, what's the point of making an application that looks like an old Office version?).

Thanks for this tip! It led me to the CMFCPopupMenu class that includes customization. I'll have to rework my base menus to be derived from CWnd instead of CObject but it gives me a place to start testing.

I didn't touch MFC for years, but I am pretty sure I may already have done it in the past, using the MFC Feature Pack, which is natively included in MFC. See the documentation of the Feature Pack and CMFCMenuBar.
